# Не изменяются данные в БД Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

У меня небольшая проблемка. Мне нужно изменить конкретное поле из выборки бд(Mysql). Но при выполнении запроса(в отдельном файле), не цепляется ID. Можете помочь исправить проблему.

Index.php:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Work');
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tasks");
$data = $_GET;
?> 

<style type="text/css">
table{
    border-spacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{ 
    background: #eee;
}
td, th{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<h1>Список дел на сегодня</h1>
<div style="float: left;">
<? if ($_GET['action'] !== 'edit') { ?>
    <form action="Add.php" method="Post">
        <input type="text" name="Text" placeholder="Описание задачи">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
<? }else{ ?>
    <form action="Edit.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="Text" placeholder="Изменить задачу">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
<? } ?>
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;">
<form method="Post">
    <label>Сортировать по</label>
    <select name="sort_by">
        <option value="date_added">Дате</option>
        <option value="is_done">Статусу</option>
        <option value="description">Описанию</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Сортировать</button>
</form>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Описание задачи</th>
        <th>Дата добавления</th>
        <th>Статус</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
      <? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
     <tbody>
        <td><? echo $row['description'] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row['date_added'] ?></td>
        <td><? if ($row['is_done'] == 1) {
            echo "<p style='color: green;'>Выполнено</p>";
        }else{
            echo "<p style='color: orange;'>В процессе</p>";
        } ?></td>
        <td><a href="Index.php?action=edit&id=<? echo $row['id'] ? 
        >&Text=">Изменить</a> <a href="">Выполнить</a> <a href="Del.php?Id= 
        <? echo $row['id'] ?>">Удалить</a></td>
    </tbody>
<? } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Edit.php:

```
<?php
require "Index.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$Edit = $db->query("UPDATE tasks SET is_done = '0' AND description = '". $data['Text'] ."' WHERE id = '".  $data['id'] ."'");
var_dump($Edit);
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну а как у тебя прицепится id, если ты его не передаёшь в Edit.php через форму?

Вот твоя форма:

```
<form action="Edit.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="Text" placeholder="Изменить задачу">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Где тут id, а?

Comment: Да...Но если я цепляю, то он пропадает при переходе на edit.php

Comment: Он заменяется на Text =

Comment: Я догадался! Я использовал для вывода id $_GET, а информацию Text запихнул в $_POST. Впервые встретился с этим.

Comment: Чтоб всё заработало - нужно скрытое поле с id добавить в эту форму.